# SVR keeps predicting flat line

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I was trying to implement the support vector regression on predicting return in the future by 'feeding' it with returns of last five days. Here's a link for the idea: http://www.quintuitive.com/2012/11/30/trading-with-support-vector-machines-svm/

Unfortunately, no matter how I changed the parameter (kernel, C or gamma), it kept giving a flat predicting line. Right now I'm completely lost at what's going wrong and any help here would be much appreciated.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import csv
import datetime, time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = np.array([row for row in csv.reader(open('eurusd_curncy.20140616.csv', 'rb'))])
data = data[1:,]

n_sample = 5000
n_data = data.shape[0]
t = data[:,0]
high = map(float,data[:,2])
low = map(float,data[:,4])
open_price = map(float,data[:,6])
close_price = map(float,data[:,5])
ret = np.zeros((n_data,1))

for i in range(n_data):
    tm = time.strptime(t[i],"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    tm = datetime.datetime(tm.tm_year,tm.tm_mon,tm.tm_mday,tm.tm_hour,tm.tm_min)
    t[i] = time.mktime(tm.timetuple())

t = map(float, t)

for i in range(n_data-1):
    ret[i] =  np.log(close_price[i+1]/close_price[i])

lag = 5
y = ret[lag:(lag+n_sample):lag]
y = y[:,0]
X = np.zeros((len(y),lag))

for i in range(len(y)):
    for j in range(lag):
        X[i,j] = ret[i+j]  

n_train = 800
trainX = X[:n_train]
trainY = y[:n_train]
testX  = X[n_train:]
testY = y[n_train:]

svr = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, epsilon=0.2, gamma=0.0001)
svr.fit(trainX, trainY)
predSvr = svr.predict(testX)


plt.plot(testY, testY, 'c.', label='true data')
plt.plot(testY, predSvr, 'm.', label='SVR')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The 'eurusd_curncy.20140616.csv' is nothing special and you can try some other data if you want. The result is a flat line that crosses the true data. I would've added a image here if I have got enough reputation. :(

Can somebody shed some light on this? Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: Shouldn't those lines be `plt.plot(testX, ...`?

Comment: @DanGetz: testX is a N by 5 matrix. plot(testX, ...) doesn't make any sense, does it?

Answer (score 0):

because your SVR doesn't contain proper value of GAMMA and C

Comment: Hey Sukhlal, Welcome to StackOverflow. You should explain your answers properly. Please go through the "how-to answer " guideline . https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer